# selecteditem or selectedindex for listpicker

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, indexing, selecteditem, listpicker

When App opens, selectedItem of the ListPicker namely, "BackgroundColor" must be from variable. How to achieve this?

**XAML:**

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="PickerItemTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding BackGroundColorString}" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="PickerFullModeItemTemplate" >
        <Grid x:Name="rootGrid" Margin="0">
             <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"  Margin="0 14 0 0" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <TextBlock Name="BackgroundColor" 
                            Text="{Binding BackGroundColorString}"
                            FontSize="35" 
                            Margin="10,10"                              
                            TextAlignment="Center"
                           FontFamily="/Assets/Fonts/AGENCYR.TTF#Agency FB"
               />
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>        

<toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="BackgroundColor"  FullModeHeader="Select Background Color:" 
                    Header="Background Color:" BorderThickness="0" 
                    FullModeItemTemplate="{StaticResource PickerFullModeItemTemplate}" 
                    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PickerItemTemplate}" Background="#FF09043C" 
                    SelectionChanged="BackgroundColor_SelectionChanged" >
 </toolkit:ListPicker>
```

**C#:**

```
public class BackGroundlistPickerClass
{
    public string BackGroundColorString
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

List<BackGroundlistPickerClass> BackGroundColorList = new List<BackGroundlistPickerClass>();

public void ImplementListPickeritems() //Listpickers
{
    BackGroundColorList.Add(new BackGroundlistPickerClass() { BackGroundColorString = "White (Default)" });
    BackGroundColorList.Add(new BackGroundlistPickerClass() { BackGroundColorString = "Black" });
    BackGroundColorList.Add(new BackGroundlistPickerClass() { BackGroundColorString = "Light Grey" });

}

string PreSelectedColor="Black";
private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundColor.SelectedItem=PreSelectedColor; //  ERROR COMES ON THIS LINE
}
```

`BackgroundColor.SelectedItem` is not working because, items in `BackgroundColor` are acutaly from Class/List. Now how to set BackgroundColor listpicker to Black(PreSelectedColor) whenever the page opens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `SelectedItem` to an item from the `ItemsSource`. You can try this way, assuming that `BackGroundColorList` property used for `ItemsSource` :

```
string PreSelectedColor="Black";
private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var defaultColor = 
            BackGroundColorList.FirstOrDefault(o => o.BackGroundColorString == PreSelectedColor);
    BackgroundColor.SelectedItem = defaultColor;
}
```